# How do you choose between 450 V vs. 750 V as a power source for your EV?

Tags: batteries, induction-motor

I am wondering what the decision factors are to help choose between 450 V DC and 750 V DC power source for an EV (electric vehicle).

The propulsion system is available in voltages between 350v and 750v. Other than the obvious price of parts, weight, parts availability and torque available, i was wondering if there was a factor i was maybe overlooking. Are there white papers on the subject?

Yes i did look on google first and found nothing that interesting on the subject.

Comment: Lower voltage needs less clearance but for the same power has to pass more current. Both have positives and negatives, unless someone says otherwise I think it may just be a matter of opinion.

Comment: First, what is the voltage rating of the motor? 2nd: DO you plan to use MOSFET, IGBT, SiC? High voltage is usually expensive.

Comment: I agree with Jarrod. Both 450 V and 750 V batteries have positives and negatives (as do all others). ;^)

Comment: As a general rule, 450 to 600 VDC is the upper limit for off-the-shelf parts. Above those values parts start to fall into an 'industrial' category, with large part sizes and a high cost.

Comment: @transister, ha, an unintentional pun I suppose ;-)

Answer (score 3):

Both are in the same safety class, so must be robustly insulated, but an arc won't jump through dry clothing, so there is little to choose there.

750v needs thinner wires for the same power, but, at the scale of a car, this matters very little.

The main difference will be the availability of semi conductors, and motors. You will be using stock semiconductors, you may be using a stock or a custom motor. As the semiconductors get up over 1000v withstanding (you need the margin for transients) their resistance increases more than proportionately.

I would strongly suspect there is a greater variety of parts available for  450v applications than 750v applications. Though if those available for 750v are the right ones at the right price, that's not a problem. Given their size, support around the world need not be different due to availability either.

The rational way to choose between the two is to build a honkin' great spreadsheet listing costs and efficiencies of good designs at both voltages. Then you have to arbitraily choose some weighting factors to reduce all your efficiencies, weights, availabilties etc to a pseudo cost, so that you compare each solution as a pure cost comparison. Warning, choose different weightings, and you might get a different result.

The irrational, but far faster, way to compare the two is to start an outline design of each. If you come across a killer reason why one route is impossible, or so much better than the other, then use that reason to make your decision. If that doesn't happen within a week, then toss a coin.

Comment: Electronic parts (IGBT) used for 3ph 400/480VAC (560/675 VDC link) are rated for 1200VDC, while for 690VAC system a 1700V components are used. Now it's up to you to make a decision if at 750VDC you have still enough margin.